# Can't update opensuse from 11.4 to 12.1 because of lack of space in /var

Tags: linux, updates, opensuse-11.4, zypper

I'm trying to update opensuse from 11.4 to 12.1. Needable size of download is more than 1.0 GB, but my filesystem /var is precisely 1.0 GB, that's why zypper stops while downloading .rpm packages because of lack of space in /var.

What are probable decisions of this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you "stretch" the partition containing /var in yast? If not, create a new partition somewhere and create a new /var there.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make a new /var that is bigger than your current one.

This should be done offline, so use a live CD so that you can modify the OS.  The following assumes

1. / (root) is /dev/sda1
2. /var is /dev/sda2
3. You will create a new /var in /dev/sda3

Boot the livecd, and make some mountpoints:

```
mkdir /mnt/root
mkdir /mnt/var
mkdir /mnt/newvar
```

Now use parted or fdisk to create a new partition for var - /dev/sda3

Then make a filesystem in /dev/sda3 for the new var:

```
mkfs.ext4 /dev/sda3
```

Mount everything:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/root
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/var
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt/newvar
```

Now copy everything from the old var to the new var:

```
rsync -ax --progress /mnt/var/ /mnt/newvar/
```

Now edit the /mnt/root/etc/fstab file to reflect the new var location:

```
/dev/sdb3             /var                   ext4    defaults        0 0
```

Then reboot.

Note that you will need to modify the devs to match your setup, and make sure the fstab line contains the appropriate filesystem (you do not have to use ext4, just a suggestion)